# replace UseWebpackDevMiddleware in .NET Core 3?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, webpack-dev-server

I have a project started w/ .NET Core 2.2 and in Startup.cs it uses UseWebpackDevMiddleware to add webpack-dev-middleware to the pipeline.

UseWebpackDevMiddleware (Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices) is now obsolete in .NET core 3, and it no longer works w/ the webpack-dev-middleware v4 (probably because npm package aspnet-webpack is no longer updated). I'm looking for some examples or documentation to help me migrate it to .net core 3.

Comment: [Use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webpackdevmiddleware.usewebpackdevmiddleware?view=aspnetcore-3.0),you can see more details [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore/issues/12890).

Answer (score 0):

Add this in package.json

"Scripts"{
"build" :"webpack"
}

To reflect web changes run "npm run build"